# The best practice of saving single-write insert-only many-entry narrow-table db in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I use sqlite 3.12 to save data. The data

1. has only one writer
2. there is no other reader to access the data before the write is done
3. has only insertion. There is no deletion.
4. During insertion, the writer does not query the data either.
5. My plain data size is like 1G. It is like a narrow table with 2-3 columns. And each row is a recorded data entry.

I was wondering what is the best practice to get the best write performance. I found

1. turn off sync and journal:
   http://blog.teamleadnet.com/2012/03/sqlite-performance-tuning.html
2. use only one transaction for all insertions: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Performance-with-journal-mode-off-td67928.html

After the above setting, profiler shows sqlite3 mostly works in btree and page read. The write (1G plain data) took more than 15m. The final db size is 2G.

[image]

I also analyzed the db by sqlite_analyzer.

1. Its index takes only 0.2% space, and 30% is used by meta data.
2. The db has only 2 tables.
3. One table has 77M entries, and uses 1.4G storage. The table has only two columns. One is an int key, the other is a double value.
4. The second table has 38M entries, and uses 640M storage. The table has 3 columns: a composed key by the two int columns, and a double value.

Is this performance expected?  Is it the best performance of data write?

Comment: Might be OK, depending on the hardware. To reduce OS reads, increase the [cache size](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size). Show the database schema.

Comment: @CL The other article https://blog.devart.com/increasing-sqlite-performance.html suggests that cache/page sizes do not matter in linux. I am a bit surprised about this..

Comment: That page does not mention Linux, and it is about one specific test whose data fits entirely even into the smallest cache size used.

Comment: @CL my db schema is simple: CREATE TABLE t1 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value NUMERIC); CREATE TABLE t2 (id1 INTEGER, id2 INTEGER, value NUMERIC, PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2)) without rowid;

Comment: Are you inserting the IDs in order?

Comment: @CL t1' id is inserted in order increased by 1. t2's id1 is actually from t1's id. t2's id2 is from another small table t3 (create table t3 (id integer primary key);). And t3's id is also increased by 1 after each insertion. When inserting to t2, its id1 and id2 are in sequence like (1,1) (2,1) (3,1) ... (N,1) (1,2) (2,2) ... (N, 2), ...

Comment: Then you should make `id2` the first column of the primary key.